# Use undo command in VBA for powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, undo

I am trying to find a way to access the `undo command` in powerpoint using VBA. In excel, It is easy because `Application.Undo` works perfectly but in powerpoint it doesn't work. Does it have a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call it this way:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Undo"
```

which will also work in Excel.

**Important!** `"Undo"` need to written exactly as presented.